# What is the propper way to use Python emcee in Julia

Tags: python, python-2.7, julia

I want to use Python's [emcee](http://dfm.io/emcee/current/) in Julia, so after a little research I found [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl), then according to their documentation I had to use

```
using PyCall
@pyimport emcee
```

But I got this error

ERROR: PyError (ccall(@pysym(:PyImport_ImportModule), PyPtr, (Cstring,), name)

The Python package emcee could not be found by pyimport. Usually this means
that you did not install emcee in the Python version being used by PyCall.
PyCall is currently configured to use the Julia-specific Python distribution
installed by the Conda.jl package.  To install the emcee module, you can
use `pyimport_conda("emcee", PKG)`, where PKG is the Anaconda
package the contains the module emcee, or alternatively you can use the
Conda package directly (via `using Conda` followed by `Conda.add` etcetera).

Alternatively, if you want to use a different Python distribution on your
system, such as a system-wide Python (as opposed to the Julia-specific Python),
you can re-configure PyCall with that Python.   As explained in the PyCall
documentation, set ENV["PYTHON"] to the path/name of the python executable
you want to use, run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia.

) 
ImportError('No module named emcee',)

So I found the directory where emcee is installed (/Users/Angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7) and I ran the command:

```
pyimport_conda("emcee","/Users/Angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7")
```

But I still get errors, this time

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- /users/angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/noarch

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"/Users/Angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7"` is not package name. You could try `pyimport_conda("emcee","emcee", "astropy")` - maybe it'll install emcee. If it doesn't help then you could try other way: `ENV["PYTHON"] = "/Users/Angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7"; Pkg.build("PyCall")` (and restart Julia).

Answer (score 1):

Do `pip install <pkg>` with the Python distribution used by Julia.
Not all python packages can be installed using conda. For Windows/Linux/Mac x32,x64 check here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs
`@pyimport emcee` worked for me with no errors

Answer (score 1):

You can use emcee directly in julia. Here is the package

https://github.com/madsjulia/AffineInvariantMCMC.jl